# Can I customize Stack Overflow's display (e.g. hide "The Overflow Blog" box)?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, blog, sidebar

I was wondering if there's some way to get rid of the box over in the upper-right corner of the Stack Overflow display ("The Overflow Blog" and so on). It's in effect distracting clickbait, and if I'm looking at a Stack Overflow page, I'm trying to focus on something, I don't need any "You might also like" links in my face.

Comment: Maybe some userscript or stylish can help, for inspiration: https://stackapps.com/questions/4758/simplify-community-bulletin-widget

Comment: You can just block the element with an ad-blocker (assuming you're using one).